# Nested Jekyll liquid objects to pull _data file by today's date

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, liquid

I have a Jekyll site with a _data directory full of files organized by date:

```
/_data/
   mydata_2020-08-28.json
   mydata_2020-08-29.json
   mydata_2020-08-30.json
   mydata_2020-08-31.json
```

I'd like to pull data from these files based on today's date, but I can't quite seem to get it right.

Let's say that I want to pull data from `{{ site.data.mydata_2020-08-31.somefield }}`, but I want to dynamically generate the date `(YYYY-MM-DD)` as today's date using `{{ 'now' | date: "%Y-%m-%d" }}`. I need to insert the date object into the data file object, but I can't find a way to do it.

I've tried:

```
{{ site.data.mydata_{{ 'now' | date: "%Y-%m-%d" }}.somefield }}
```

but it returns the truncated end of my liquid object:

```
.somefield
```

And I tried:

```
{{site.data.mydata_| append: 'now' | date: "%Y-%m-%d" | append:.somefield}}
```

which returns today's date:

```
2020-08-31
```

I also read through most of the documentation at https://shopify.github.io/liquid/, but maybe I'm overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch data based on the date in your case, try with the following:

```
{% assign today_data = 'now' | date: "%Y-%m-%d" | prepend: 'mydata_' %}

# You can fetch data file with particular date as follows:
{{ site.data[today_data] }}
```

**NOTE:** `.somefield` can't be fetched in above approach.

Comment: Thanks, but I would need to be able to pull the contents from within the data, using something like .somefield. The idea would be that a data file would be automatically added each day, and my pages would pull data from inside the most recent file.

Comment: That is not possible as far as I have used Jekyll. Maybe try reanalyzing your structures.